# Where can I find some reputable resellers of Casascius.Physical Bitcoins?

Tags: physical-coins

Casacsius [stopped selling physical bitcoins](http://casascius.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/orders-now-accepted-by-invitation-only/) directly on April 1st 2013, and instead refers people to resellers.

Where can I find some reputable resellers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casascius has resumed selling individual and rolls of coins on the official website, https://www.casascius.com/. Individual coins will be sold for a limited time only.

It is still possible to save money on individual coins by buying through resellers.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.goldxcash.net/buycasasciusbitcoins.htm

Casascius Physical Bitcoins, physical coins loaded with bicoin buy online.

Comment: What is your experience with this reseller? Why do you recommend them?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find sellers on bitmit.net.  You can also use esgrow there to assure that you have no issues with your transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Reliable Casascius and Recalescence coins reseller! Our store has been working from 2012 and is now shipping to European countries. Take a loot at https://btcstore.eu

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using escrow in the markets on the Bitcoin forums is a safe and easy method. Markup is quite high at this time, December 2015.